# Parsing: load into memory or use stream

Tags: c, parsing

I'm writing a little parser and I would like to know the advantages and disadvantages of the different ways to load the data to be parsed. The two ways that I thought of are:

- Load the file's contents into a string then parse the string (access the character at an array position)
- Parse as reading the file stream (`fgetc`)

The former will allow me to have two functions: one for `parse_from_file` and `parse_from_string`, however I believe this mode will take up more memory. The latter will not have that disadvantage of using more memory.

Does anyone have any advice on the matter?

Comment: Are you particularly short of memory?

Comment: @Neil Not necessarily, however, I would like the memory footprint to be as small as possible.

Comment: Why? My point is, is that a constraint? If not, you should normally prefer to read as much as possible into memory, and parse it there.

Comment: @Neil, even if it's not for OP, it might later be a constraint for someone else using the code. There may be reasons to implement it by loading everything into memory first, but "load it in memory unless you have a good reason not to" sounds like backwards reasoning to me.

Comment: @R. We will have to differ on that then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading the entire file in or memory mapping it will be faster, but may cause issues if you want your language to be able to `#include` other files as these would be memory mapped or read into memory as well.

The stdio functions would work well because they usually try to buffer up data for you, but they are also general purpose so they also try to look out for usage patterns which differ from reading a file from start to finish, but that shouldn't be too much overhead.

A good balance is to have a large circular buffer (x * 2 * 4096 is a good size) which you load with file data and then have your tokenizer read from.  Whenever a block's worth of data has been passed to your tokenizer (and you know that it is not going to be pushed back) you can refill that block with new data from the file and update some buffer location info.

Another thing to consider is if there is any chance that the tokenizer would ever need to be able to be used to read from a pipe or from a person typing directly in some text.  In these cases your reads may return less data than you asked for without it being at the end of the file, and the buffering method I mentioned above gets more complicated.  The stdio buffering is good for this as it can easily be switched to/from line or block buffering (or no buffering).

Using gnu fast lex (flex, but not the Adobe Flash thing) or similar can greatly ease the trouble with all of this.  You should look into using it to generate the C code for your tokenizer (lexical analysis).

Whatever you do you should try to make it so that your code can easily be changed to use a different form of next character peek and consume functions so that if you change your mind you won't have to start over.

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient on a POSIX system would probably neither of the two (or a variant of the first if you like): just map the file read-only with `mmap`, and parse it then. Modern systems are quite efficient with that in that they prefetch data when they detect a streaming access etc., multiple instances of your program that parse the same file will get the same physical pages of memory etc. And the interfaces are relatively simple to handle, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using lex (and perhaps yacc, if the language of your grammar matches its capabilities). Lex will handle all the fiddly details of lexical analysis for you and produce efficient code. You can probably beat its memory footprint by a few bytes, but how much effort do you want to expend into that?

Comment: gnu flex has an option to use stdio or the read system call without the extra overhead of stdio.